# Why can't I connect to MariaDB with Navicat through SSH tunnel?

Tags: mysql, ssh, ssh-tunnel

I've always used Navicat on windows to manage my MySQL/Percona instances.

A few days ago I bought a new server and have installed MariaDB 10.3.9.

I can connect to it fine when I'm in a putty session SSHd into the box.  `mysql -u root -p` brings it up perfectly.

For some reason though, Navicat throws the error `access denied for user 'root'@'::1' (using password: YES)`

Navicat settings are the same that I've always used before:

Host Name: localhost
Port: 3306
Mysql username: root
Mysql password: [root's mysql password]

Use SSH tunnel: yes
IP address: [my server's ip]
SSH username: [my name]
SSH password: [my ssh password]

I'm not sure why it'd work over SSH when I manually do it, but not when Navicat does it, even though it's presumably doing largely the same thing.  What's the `'::1'` bit about, does that point to the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `::1` is the IP address of `localhost`. Check your server's `/etc/hosts` file and make sure it's present.

Comment: `127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6`


yep.  It's a clean install of centos 7 (or was before I added the DB etc)

Comment: OK, so whose build of MariaDB did you install? How did you configure it post-installation?

Comment: I've worked out the problem.  I think.  I changed the root password from blank to a password of my choice.  When I log in on the box I use that password successfully.  When I log in via navicat I get the error... unless I use a blank password and then it works.  So are there two subtly different root users on mysql?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there are *three* subtly different root users in MySQL. (Which is a real pain, but it's been this way forever and probably won't change...)

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select Host, User from mysql.user where User = 'root';
+-----------+------+
| Host      | User |
+-----------+------+
| 127.0.0.1 | root |
| ::1       | root |
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
3 rows in set (0.06 sec)
```

The user `root` with host `localhost` is only used when connecting using the UNIX socket. The other users are used when connecting via the TCP socket, via IPv4 or IPv6 respectively.

When you do your ssh port forwarding with Navicat, the TCP socket is used, and specifically the IPv6 TCP socket (as IPv6 is preferred over IPv4). So that user is the one being authenticated against.

Most of us deal with this by making sure the password is set the same for all three rows.

Comment: Perfect.  How do I go about changing the password on the other ones?  I just tried when logged in as root::1 using `set password = password('hunter2');` and got the message `You are using MariaDB as an anonymous user and anonymous users are not allowed to modify user settings`

Comment: You'll have to login from the server itself, not through navicat. Then you can `ALTER USER 'root'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY 'hunter2';` (and repeat for 127.0.0.1).

Comment: Thanks. AFK at the moment but I'll try tomorrow! FWIW I was logged in on the server, but as root::1, not just root. I'll try tomorrow!

Comment: So this kind of worked, but I had to do `'root'@'127.0.0.1'` and `'root'@'<myhostname>'` as well.  Yep, I seem to have FOUR root users...

Comment: I've now run `mysql_secure_installation` which would have been the easier fix, I believe.  It's removed the `'root'@'<hostname>'` account, so I'm back to the normal 3.

Comment: Oops! I had assumed you already ran `mysql_secure_installation`, as it's dangerous to do anything with MariaDB without having done so.

Comment: Never used MariaDB before, I didn't even know it was a thing.  I'll read the manual more closely next time...

Comment: Well, the same has been true of MySQL before it for years, so if you've used that...

Comment: I last did an install five years ago, I remember some faff with setting root passwords, but who knows...